# Trying to multiply two values from lists

Tags: python

I am trying to multiply 2 items from 2 lists to create a third number.  I have been recieving the following error:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`

```py
Fruit ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"]
Fruitweights [ 4,3,2,1]

Color ["blue", "purple", "black", "red"]
Colorweights [7,5,3,1]

elements = {}

elements["Fruits"] = random.choices(Fruit, Fruitweights)[0]
elements["Colors"] = random.choices(Color, ColorWeights)[0]
    
allweights = Fruitweights * Colorweights
    
elements["rank"] = allweights
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on how I can fix!

Comment: Your example boils down to `[4,3,2,1] * [7,5,3,1]`. What numbers are you attempting to multiply?

Comment: I am trying to pick a random number from each list and multiply them

Answer (score 1):

```
Fruitweights = [4, 3, 2, 1]
Colorweights = [7, 5, 3, 1]

allweights = [x * y for x, y in zip(Fruitweights, Colorweights)]
print(allweights)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot multiply lists as if they're vectors - that is simply not how Python lists work. If you want to do that, I suggest using numpy arrays (from the `numpy` [package](https://numpy.org/)):

```
import numpy as np
Fruitweights = np.array([4,3,2,1])
Colorweights = np.array([7,5,3,1])
allweights = Fruitweights * Colorweights

print(allweights)  # [28 15  6  1]
```

Comment: I am not looking to multiple the whole list, just a random item from each list

Answer (score 0):

```
[x * y for x, y in zip(arr1,arr2)]
```

Assuming you want pairwise multiplication. If you want Cartesian product, look at `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 0):

In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69048866/trying-to-multiply-two-values-from-lists#comment122035492_69048866):

> I am trying to pick a random number from each list and multiply them

Just use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) which returns one random element from the given list.

```py
import random 

Fruitweights = [4, 3, 2, 1]
Colorweights = [7, 5, 3, 1]

allweights = random.choice(Fruitweights) * random.choice(Colorweights)
print(allweights)  # e.g. 15
```